# Swift Bond compile error in NSObject+KVO.swift file

Tags: swift, swiftbond

I have installed Bond 6.2.6 with CocoaPods.
While building my project, an error has appeared in the file:

```
<my_proj>\Pods\Bond\Sources\Bond\Shared\NSObject+KVO.swift
```

The error:

```
.../NSObject+KVO.swift:239:81: Cannot convert value of type '(_, _) -> UnownedUnsafe<NSObject>' to expected argument type '(_, UnownedUnsafe<NSObject>) -> _'
```

Source code:

```
deallocationDisposable.otherDisposable = object._willDeallocate.reduce(nil, {$1}).observeNext { object in
  if self.observing {
    object?.unbox.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: self.keyPath, context: &self.context)
  }
}
```

Commenting it gave me the ability to build my project. But it's probably not the best practice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated Xcode to the latest (8.3.2). Now it works.